# A problem regarding Kernel and Range of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have two linear maps $S$ and $T$ each from $V$ to $V$ such that Ker $S$= Ker $T$ and Range $S$= Range $T$ and $V$ is the direct sum of Ker (S) and Range (S). Does that imply $S=T$.

Answer (score 2):

No. Let $T=2S$ for any nonzero $S$.

Comment: Assuming the underlying field has characteristic $\ne 2$.

Comment: what is characteristic? Asker may not know what characteristic is! you are confusing the asker

Comment: @Alex: is it true if one map is adjoint of the other.

Comment: @user103623 Not in general, for example any invertable non-symmetric matrix provides a counterexample.

Comment: @DonAnselmo I think you complaint is unreasonable. I made the necessary comment for my answer to be correct, and put it as a comment to avoid confusing the asker. Do you want me to delete the comment, making my answer incorrect, or to define characteristic?

Comment: Just define characteristic as not to confuse the  asker. Also, I don't see how my "complaint" is unreasonable. Can you explain this?

Comment: @DonAnselmo I think that would be even more confusing, unless they've seen finite fields, in which case they almost certainly know what characteristic is. So my options are essentially limited to 1) what I did, which I don't think is very confusing or 2) teach a full class day's worth of algebra.

Comment: Sorry for using the word "confusing", I really meant: It is not polite to the asker. Definitely, you do not need to define what you write. But, if you are nice, you can give a definition of what characteristic is. I assume asker is in a basic linear algebra class and not in an abstract algebra class, hence talking about characteristic probably wont be helpful for him. You do not need to teach a full class day's worth of algebra.

Comment: Maybe you should just add the sidenote that living in a field of characteristic $2$ is living without even people.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are many ways in which this can fail. A simple one is to take any pair of distinct invertible maps $V\to V$. Or to compose any projection with a non-trivial automorphism of its image space.

Comment: And this even works over the two-element field, as long as $\dim V\geq2$.